# DatePicker and TimePicker crash when I press the Set button

Tags: java, android, datepicker, timepicker

I am making a messenger that has date and time pickers pop up when I click the button. When I press the Set button to display them, the app crashes. My code is:

```
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        yearSet = year;
        monthSet = monthOfYear + 1;
        daySet = dayOfMonth;
        btnDate.setText(yearSet + monthSet + daySet);
        }
    };

    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hour, int minute) {
        hourSet = hour;
        minuteSet = minute;
        btnTime.setText(hourSet + minuteSet);
        }
    };
```

**LogCat:**

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
          android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f4
          at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:1068)
          at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4546)
          at devncode.kemo.testApp.SendMessageActivity$3.onDateSet(SendMessageActivity.java:95)
          at android.app.DatePickerDialog.tryNotifyDateSet(DatePickerDialog.java:199)
          at android.app.DatePickerDialog.onClick(DatePickerDialog.java:154)
          at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:185)
          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Change your `setText` to `btnDate.setText(yearSet + monthSet + daySet+ "");`

Comment: Thank you Prerak, it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are setting text of different items as integers.. For example `btn.setText(int);` where it should be a string `btn.setText(String);`

So to fix it, wherever you have something like

```
btnTime.setText(hourSet + minuteSet);
```

change it to

```
btnTime.setText(hourSet + minuteSet + "");
```

Adding the `+ ""` will cast it as a String and not give an error.